# Can I use IntelliJ to develop WSO2 ESB API?

Tags: intellij-idea, wso2, wso2-esb

I am using the WSO2 Eclipse version to develop my WSO2 ESB project.

I am asking if exist something like of an IntelliJ plugin to develop my WSO2 ESB API into IntelliJ Idea IDE. I mean something that shows the graphical flows.

Is it possible or not?

Comment: There is none at the moment.

Comment: Most of time i just use text editor with xml support to write all i need. And extensibly use IntellJ Idea to write xslt tranfrormations for WSOESB.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there is no IdeaJ plugin that you can use. You need to use the WSO2 Developer studio which is based on eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can ,I have used intellij for this but there is no plugin available for it.But you can use it without plugin as well.